# Clamping Schottky Leakage Current

Tags: voltage-clipping

[image]

I'm trying to understand how the leakage current of D1 will affect the above circuit. From point A to point B I have a lengthy cable whose characteristic impedance is unknown. Because of the length of the cable the falling edges often undershoot and go down to as much as -1.5V (and sometimes more).

To counter this I'm using a clamping diode to cut off the excess voltage. However, the [PMEG1020EA](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PMEG1020EA.pdf) has a leakage current of upto 2 mA @ 5V. My question is, how would this affect my circuit?

The diode will be reversed biased when the signal settles down to 3.3V. Let's assume the leakage current is 2 mA at 3.3V as well. When the signal settles to 3.3 V, the diode will draw 2 mA. But if the diode draws 2 mA it means that the voltage across R1 is 2 V and so the voltage at X is just 1.3 V. So this scheme clearly doesn't work with a diode which has a large leakage current. Would I be correct in that conclusion?

But because the voltage at X is just 1.3 V now, wouldn't the leakage current now decrease?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the leakage current of D1 causes a voltage accross R1, which lowers the on-state voltage.  Use a lower R1 or a better diode.

There are other Schottky diodes that have less leakage than 2 mA.  Even this one probably has much lower leakage at 25°C.  If you know it will always be operating at that temperature or less, then you can use the lower leakage figure.  If it has to work at high temperatures, then select a better Schottky or perhaps resort to a ordinary silicon diode, like 1N4148 or equivalent.  That's a nice and fast diode, but will have higher forward drop so therefore clip the undershoots at a lower level.  Everything is a tradeoff.

Answer (score 3):

Like you already guessed, and Olin confirmed, you simply need a diode with a lower leakage current. 2 mA is *a lot*, but is typical for Schottky's which offer a low forward voltage at high current. Your PMEG1020EA has a voltage drop of maximum 350 mV at 1 A. The [RB751](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/RB751_SER.pdf) has a comparable voltage drop, but at the lower current of 1 mA. It's also rated at 120 mA, but that's more than enough for your application.

And for that you get a much lower leakage current of maximum 0.5 µA at 25 °C. This will cause a voltage drop across R1 of merely 0.5 mV. Olin said something about temperature, and that might be something to pay attention to. Leakage current is a lot higher at higher temperatures:

[image]

I'll assume that your den won't get as hot as 125 °C, but let's check for 85 °C, sauna temperature. Reverse voltage is only 3.3 V, so we're at the left of the graph. At 25 °C we have typical less than 20 nA, but with 2 µA it is 100 \$\times\$ as high at 85 °C! Still no worries, it's only a 2 mV drop across R1.

But what happened with our 0.5 µA? That was a *maximum* value, graphs in datasheets will almost always give you *typical* values. It doesn't say what the maximum at 85 °C will be. So we have to guesstimate: if the maximum is also 100 \$\times\$ the maximum at 25 °C we get 50 µA, at 85 °C. That's good for a 50 mV drop across R1. For a logic level definitely OK, especially since you won't use it in the sauna anyway.

The [1N4148](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/1N4148_1N4448.pdf) will have comparable performance, but a a higher forward voltage, allowing the undershoot to go lower. It's up to you to decide whether that's acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the RB751. But I think I found a better one in PMEG2005EH. The leakage is higher (40uA, so 40mV drop on R1) but the forward drop is just 240mV at 10mA. The capacitance is higher (80pF), though, which will slow down the signal somewhat. I was looking at the 10mA for Vf because thats my estimate what the current will be. Assuming the undershoot goes down to -1 V, the diode will clip 0.24V, so 0.76 is dropped on R2. I = 13mA. Would you say the PMEG2005EH is a better choice?

Comment: @Saad - if the clamping voltage is important to you the PMEG2005EH is better than the RB751, which has a 400 mV drop at 10 mA. 40 uA is better than your first diode, but you'll have to make the same reasoning like I did in my answer to see if it's still OK at higher temperatures. You probably don't need 85 °C, but then the leakage current would be 4 mA! If you can keep it cool the PMEG2005EH is a good choice.